# Ansible access same variables from multiple Json files

Tags: ansible

I have multiple .json files on local host where I place my playbook:

```
json-file-path/{{ testName }}.json
```

{{ testName }}.json are: testA.json, testB.json, testC.json ... etc.

All .json files have same keys with different values like this:

json-file-path/testA.json:

```
{
   “a_key”: “a_value1”
   “b_key”: “b_value1”
 }
```

json-file-path/testB.json:

```
{
   “a_key”: “a_value2”
   “b_key”: “b_value2”
 }
```

json-file-path/testC.json:

```
{
   “a_key”: “a_value3”
   “b_key”: “b_value3”
 }

.....
```

I need to access the key-value variables from all .json files and if the values meet some condition, I will perform some task in target host. For example, I have:

```
a_value1=3
a_value2=4
a_value3=1
```

I go through my .json file one by one, if a_key[value]>3, I will copy this .json file to target host, otherwise skip the task. In this case, I will only copy testC.json to target host.

How would I achieve this? I was thinking of re-constructing my .json files using {{ testName }} as dynamic key of dict like this:

```
 {
    “testName”: “testA”
        {
           “a_key”: “a_value1”
           “b_key”: “b_value1”
  }
```

So I can access my variable as {{ testName}}.a_key. So far I haven’t been able to achieve this.

I have tried the following in my playbook:

```
—-
- host: localhost 
  tasks:
    - name: construct json files
      vars:
        my_vars:
          a_key: “{{ a_value }}”
          b_key: “{{ b_value }}”
        with_dict: “{{ testName }}”
      copy:
        content: “{{ my_vars | to_nice_json }}”
        dest: /json-file-path/{{ testName }}.json
```

My updated playbook are:

```
/mypath/tmp/include.yaml:

—-
- hosts: remote_hostName
  tasks:
  - name: load json files
    set_fact:
      json_data: “{{ lookup(‘file’, item) | from_json }}”
  - name: copy json file if condition meets
    copy:
      src: “{{ item }}”
      dest: “{{ /remote_host_path/tmp}}/{{item | basename }}”
    delegate_to: “{{ remote_hostName }}”
    when: json_data.a_key|int>5

/mypath/test.yml:
—-
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    local_src_ dir: /mypath/tmp
    remote_host: remote_hostName
    remote_dest_dir: /remote_host_path/tmp
  tasks:
    - name: looping
      include: include.yaml
      with_fileglob:
         - “{{ local_src_dir }}/*json”
```

All json files on localhost under /mypath/tmp/.

Latest version of playbook. It is working now:

```
/mypath/tmp/include.yaml:
—-
- name: loafing json flies
  include_vars:
    file: “{{ item }}”
    name: json_data
- name: copy json file to remote if condition meets
  copy: 
    src: “{{ item }}”
    dest: ‘/remote_host_path/tmp/{{item | basename}}’
  delegate_to: “{{ remote_host }}”
  when: json_data.a_key > 5

/mypath/test.yml:

—-
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    local_src_dir: /mypath/tmp
    remote_host: remote_hostName
    remote_dest_dir: /remote_host_path/tmp
  tasks:
    - name: looping json files
      include: include.yaml
      with_fileglob:
         - “{{ local_src_dir }}”/*json”
```

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that I have understood your requirements correctly, and that this helps move you forward.

Fundamentally, you can load each of the JSON files so you can query the values as native Ansible variables. Therefore you can loop through all the files, read each one, compare the value you are interested in and then conditionally copy to your remote host via a delegated task. Therefore, give this a try:

Create an include file `include.yaml`:

```
---
# 'item' contains a path to a local JSON file on each pass of the loop

- name: Load the json file
  set_fact:
    json_data: "{{ lookup('file', item) | from_json }}"
- name: Delegate a copy task to the remote host conditionally
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ remote_dest_dir }}/{{ item | basename }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ remote_host }}"
  when: json_data.a_key > value_threshold
```

then in your playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  # Set some example vars, tho these could be placed in a variety of places
  vars:
    local_src_dir: /some/local/path
    remote_host: <some_inventory_hostname>
    remote_dest_dir: /some/remote/path
    value_threshold: 3
  tasks:
    - name: Loop through all *json files, passing matches to include.yaml
      include: include.yaml
      loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', local_src_dir + '/*json').split(',') }}"
```

**Note:** As you are running an old version of Ansible, you may need older alternate syntax for all of this to work:

In your include file:

```
- name: Load the json file
  set_fact:
    include_vars: "{{ item }}"
- name: Delegate a copy task to the remote host conditionally
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ remote_dest_dir }}/{{ item | basename }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ remote_host }}"
  when: a_key > value_threshold
```

and in your playbook:

```
- name: Loop through all *json files, passing matches to include.yaml
  include: include.yaml
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ local_src_dir }}/*json"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @clockworknet! I tried above and was getting ‘unexpected failure in finding the lookup named ‘{{ lookup(‘fileglob’, local_srcdir + ‘/*json’).split(‘,’) }} ‘ in the available lookup plugins. ‘. What does split do here?

Comment: Hmm. That statement worked fine for me. Could you update your question with the exact code you have tried and also the version of Ansible you are using. Older versions did not support the 'fileglob' look up, but it was introduced in 1.4, which is a long time ago. The lookup returns a comma separated list of values, so `split(',')` turns the output into a list that we can loop over.

Comment: I updated my playbooks as you suggested @clockworknet. I am using Ansible 2.4

Comment: `loop: “”{{ lookup(‘fileglob’, local_src_dir + ‘/*.json’).split(‘,’) }}”` There is a typo in test.yml (two " at the start) - is that in your actual code? Also in 'include.yaml' change `when: “{{json_data.a_key|int }}”>5` to `when: json_data.a_key | int >5`. You don't use `"{{}}"` in when statements which is not always intuitive at first.

Comment: Double “ was my typo. The actual code has only one “. Thanks for pointing out {{ }} for json._data.a_key. I updated again. But still getting same error. So when I am at include: include.yaml in test.yml, the item in include.yaml will look for the output from lookup(‘fileglob’, local_src_dir...), which in my case would be /mypath/tmp/*.json, right?

Comment: Odd. Not sure why that is not working for you. The lookup will produce a list of files that match the pattern. This is then looped, so that include.yaml is called once for each match with the full path passed in as the `item` variable. I have updated my answer to include the old, alternate syntax for specifying the fileglob loop. Give that a try.

Comment: with_fileglob took care of ‘unexpected failure in finding lookup..’. Thank you so much for the suggestion! Now I am getting failure at TASK[loop]. - “ no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect path. The error appears to have been in ‘/mypath/tmp/include.yaml’ line 2 column 3...’. I can see the loop hits all my .json files as I am getting the above error for each .json file.

Comment: You code does not look like mine, according to the code in your question. You have turned `/mypath/tmp/include.yaml` into a playbook. It isn't. Also, as you are running an old version of Ansible, it may be that when you get that working, the lookup in the include file will fail. I have updated my answer to include older syntax for that portion as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It is working now! I updated my post with the latest version of working playbook.